# meteor .publish on server side: working with a client variable

Tags: meteor, chat, publish-subscribe

I am building a chat and based on the chatroom selected by the currentUser, I want to publish messages with this function:

```
Meteor.publish('messages',function(){
  return Messages.find(
    {chatId: 'QMMjBgCvLcnLvJPvx'},
    sort:{timestamp: -1}
  });
});
```

Now the chatId is still hardcoded, but it needs to be dynamic. The chatId is passed in the URL(e.g.`.../chat/QMMjBgCvLcnLvJPvx`). In the client based code I have used to read the `chatId`:

```
var chatId = Router.current().params._id;
```

*Iron Router*

But this doesn't work server side. Is there a way to send the `chatId` from the URL to the server so I use Meteor.publish as mentioned above. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: You can pass a parameter in when you subscribe to the publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the variable when you subscribe I.e.

```
Meteor.subscribe("messages", {chatId: Session.get("current-room")})
```

In the publication:

```
Meteor.publish('messages',function(chatId){
  return Messages.find(
    {chatId: chatId},
    sort:{timestamp: -1}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your route, you can subscribe to a publication and pass a param inside `waitOn` which will cause the app to show your loading template until the subscription is ready and the chatId will be reactive.

Configure loading template:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'templateName',
    loadingTemplate: 'anotherTemplateName'
});
```

Your route:

```
Router.route('/chat/:_id',{
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('messages', this.params._id);
    },

    action: function(){
        //render your template with data
        this.render('templateName', {
            data: function () {
                //will return object to the template which you can use in both HTML and JS. Also necessary for the link.
                return Somethings.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Publication:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function (chatId) {
    //the chatId comes from our subscribe in our route
    return Messages.find({chatId: chatId});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers and the hints. After some more modifications I arrived at this, which solved the issue:

```
  var chatId = Router.current().params._id
  this.wait(Meteor.subscribe('messages', chatId));
```